# Youtube API search

Tags: youtube-api

I have been trying out the youtube API with Java. When I do a search using the API I don't get the same results as when I just type the keyword in the browser, any logical explanation why this is?

Compare: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blah+&aq=f

http://pastebin.com/FVRd3URT (list of video Titles)

I also noticed that some videos (or at least their title) are duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's just how it is.  Trying to match up the two is a futile exercise.

Amazon search has the same problem.

Comment: Ok.. then I assume that every query results different results.. I just get the same result in the browser after doing a repeated search because the results are cached?

Comment: I'm not certain of the details.  I have developers I work with who code against it and they are forever lamenting that the API results are different then the web search results.  I believe it's deterministic (so caching really doesn't enter into it), just usually different between the two methods.

Answer (score 3):

YouTube API version 3 gets the same search results. Version 3 is still experimental, according to the documentation. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 1):

This demo might help.

https://github.com/bitsabhi/YouTubeDemo

A java project to return title, album, you tube link when the user searches for any songs. Uses You tube search API.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

It is as if the API queries don't support full text search - results through the API are the same as if you enter "my search query" in quotes.

Although, try setting a slightly larger time frame: 'today' might be different from 'last_week', and you may get more relevant results.

Comment: Heh I'm quite surprised that I still get answers to a question I asked two years ago :) Anyways it seems that the API didn't improve :(, haven't used it since then.