# Looking for a way to output the top viewed youtube video to a text file for a search term

Tags: perl, vbscript, youtube, youtube-api

I would like to output just the top youtube video for a particular search term, e.g Tennis to a text file. Command line options are what I prefer but am open to other solutions.

Comment: can you give some example and show what you have done so far and also include sample text file.

Comment: I have mainly looked at different options, one option is Yahoo Pipes, the other things I have looked at is Youtube Data API but I havent gotten very far. I would like to use youtube-dl (command line youtube download utility) with the text file to download youtube videos. My challenge is to get the top youtube video per day in terms of number of views. I am just looking for ideas on how to do this and dont have any code as of now.

Comment: What exactly do you want to output? An FLV video file, or just a title and URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data you need in XML format from [YouTube's API](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=something&orderby=viewCount&max-results=1&v=2).

(Note: [The results may differ from the HTML website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284996/youtube-api-search))

Then parse the XML with anything you want, e.g. Perl's [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::XPathContext). It's a bit fiddly though, if you haven't used that module before.

Once you have the video URL, you can pass it to youtube-dl.